# How to get an OAuth access token from Google Cloud Messaging on a remote server

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-cloud-messaging, chrome-gcm

I have a general comprehension question about OAuth access token retrieval for a Google Chrome Extension.

I have a popup HTML window in the browser that uses Jquery to request data from the server (a LAMP stack on AWS). The data is presented by PHP scripts which access a MySQL database. All very basic stuff.

I now want to implement a push messaging system using Google Cloud Messaging to alert users of new content that they can check. However I don't really understand where I should request the access token and how to listen for the response. I figure it should be in the PHP scripts but all the Google documentation that I've read states the user has to be present in order to allow access to push messaging. That tells me I should put it in the JavaScript but I feel this is a bad idea because every user could potentially request an access token when I think I only need one every 3000 seconds or so. If my app was completely implemented in PHP I'm sure this would be possible and now I'm worried that splitting it up like this leaves push messaging out of the question. Am I missing a crucial detail or just out of luck?

Comment: See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cloudMessaging.html#five.

When you call chrome.pushMessaging.getChannelId (in your Chrome extension), you're asking permission from the user.

Answer (score 0):

If the data access you need isn't user-specific, then you're right, there's no good reason to get a separate token for each user.  Check out https://developers.google.com/accounts/cookbook/roles/Apps which discusses some options.